# Нужно ли дополнительно обрабатывать пользовательский ввод в prepared statements?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

В документации по PDO сказано:

> "The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this."

Так ли это в действительности и насколько безопасно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, достаточно безопасно. Если передавать параметри через `$sth->execute(...)`, то будут использоваться квотинг как для строки, если есть какие-то тонкости при передаче, то используйте `$sth->bindParam()` - тогда можно будет указать как конретно обработать указанную переменную.